# Do the Stack Exchange employees give any reasons when marking a feature request as [status-declined]?

Tags: support, feature-request-process, stack-exchange-team

I see a lot of feature requests which are marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and they have many answers (both for and against the request). I assume that [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) must be added by SE staff and not normal Meta users.

I wanted to know whether the SE staff give any reasons while marking a feature request as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)? If yes then how do we identify from the list of answers which ones are from SE staff.

I am asking this as I wanted to know the actual reasons/limitations of the SE staff regarding why a feature-request can't be handled.

Comment: Probably worth noting that some feature-requests attract excellent answers from ordinary users explaining why they'd be undesirable; in some of those cases, no further explanation is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange employees will typically have a diamond (♦) next to their name on meta.SE.

Alternatively, you can check [the official team page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) for a full list of current employees.

Also, SE employees typically note that they work at SE in the "about me" section of their profile, so you can check there as well.

Comment: LOL exactly my thoughts :D

Comment: Now fight for the points! Round 1!

Comment: @PatrickHofman noo lazy.

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks for your reply but aren't the ones who have diamond sign, the moderators of the site and moderator can be any community member being elected by SE staff to be moderator. In that case, isn't it difficult to go through each user's profile or official team page every time to check whether the user who has answered is a SE Staff member or a normal user. I mean isn't there a direct way to distinguish between 2 users by not navigating to their profiles or official team page.

Comment: @Aby meta.SE has no moderators. Therefore, you can assume that anyone with a diamond is an employee.

Comment: Ok if thats the case then i accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons are given by employees and they typically have diamonds, and also state them being employee in their about me. Also you find employees [there](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), if you are suspicious.